# getHeight() gives values of portrait layout even though only landscape is allowed

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

EDIT:
I just found out that the XML leads to this error. When I delete "selectiontable" (drawroom uses android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/selectiontable") I get the right values for drawroom. I managed to fix it by putting selecionable and drawroom in a LinearLayout instead of a RelativeLayout and did some more changes to the XML.

I've a strange problem. In another class I've nearly the same code and it works fine there, but in this class the values for getHeight and getWidth are always wrong and seem to be the values for a portrait layout even though the phone is in landscape mode and I`ve declared it (android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape") in the manifest file. I get the correct values when I catch them after the layout has been created (tested it to catch them after a press on a button). It's really strange, because it works nearly exactly like that in my other class.
Here is the code:

```
public class SortMaterialActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private LinearLayout drawroom;
...

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sort_material);

        drawroom                = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawroom);
...
drawroom.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createCanvas();
                calcDensity();
                createMaterial();
            }
        });
}

private void createCanvas()
    {
        canvasWidth = drawroom.getWidth(); //wrong values here
        canvasHeight = drawroom.getHeight();
        storageroomHeight = storageroom.getHeight();

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvasWidth, canvasHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvasFrame.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

And here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/selectiontable"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.125"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/exitButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_heightPercent="100%"
                app:layout_aspectRatio="100%"
                android:onClick="onExitButton"
                android:background="@drawable/exit_button" />

        </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.75">
        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.125"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/checkResultButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_heightPercent="100%"
                app:layout_aspectRatio="100%"
                android:onClick="onCheckResultButton"
                android:background="@drawable/check_button"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawroom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/selectiontable"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/storageroom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:background="@drawable/storage_boundaries">
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FF8A80">
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#8C9EFF">
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/cubeframe"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#A5D6A7">
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/canvas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/drawroom"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/drawroom"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/drawroom"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/drawroom">
    </ImageView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
        android:onClick="onBackButton"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/back">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/resultButtons"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onShowOptimizationButton">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/showOptimizationView"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/showOptimizationText"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="falsch"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:gravity="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/showResultInfoView"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/showResultInfoText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:gravity="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/backButton"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_48dp"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:onClick="onBackButton"
                android:layout_below="@id/resultButtons"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/backButtonText"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="zurück"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/backButton"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/backButton"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/newtaskButton"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_replay_black_48dp"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:onClick="onRepeatButton"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/backButton"
                android:layout_below="@id/resultButtons"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:text="neue Aufgabe"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/newtaskButton"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/newtaskButton"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/OverlayExitButton"
                android:background="@drawable/exit_button"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:onClick="onExitButton"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/newtaskButton"
                android:layout_below="@id/resultButtons"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:text="beenden"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/OverlayExitButton"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/OverlayExitButton"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe the layout is not ready when you try to get those values. Depending on your needs, you could try to use `postDelayed` with 500 millis or something like that

Comment: Yes I think that's the problem. I managed to fix it by putting selecionable and drawroom in a LinearLayout instead of a RelativeLayout and did some more changes to the XML. Now it works. Seems like drawroom before was created in the wrong size, delivers the values and then is resized because it is moved to right to be on the right of selectionable.